# Help identifying this connector?

Tags: identification, connector, power-connector

Can someone help me identify this connector?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you certain it's Molex?

Comment: Please measure pin-pin pitch and hole diameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contact pitch is the last piece of the puzzle but these are so common that I'm posting it as an answer: JST VHR-3N

https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eVH.pdf